# How to force dhcp client to allow a self defined domain name

Tags: networking, dhcp, hostname, dhclient

I'm configuring a 14.04 lts server without network manager installed.

I set in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`:

```
send host-name "os-vps276.projet-okinawa.org";
supersede domain-name "projet-okinawa.org";
```

I set in `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 os-vps276.projet-okinawa.org test.projet-okinawa.org localhost
```

and `os-vps276` is set in `etc/hostname`.

When I ask `hostname` by using Terminal I got the hostname `os-vps276`, but
when I ask `hostname -f` I got an error `hostname: Name or service not known`.

Do I need to set a static ip address or set my dhcp ip and corresponding server.domain.name in my hosts configuration file ? (that has the same effect as an administrative point of view).

My goal was to get everything from the dhcp except the domain name I would like to set by myself.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

1. Edit `/etc/hostname` to contain your desired hostname

   - `vim /etc/hostname`
2. `hostname -f /etc/hostname`
3. `exit`

The next terminal you open, or your next ssh session will show the hostname in `/etc/hostname`.

Other machines on the network may still refer to your machine as the domain provided by the DHCP server, but locally your computer should respect the contents of this file.

Comment: You didn't understand, may be I explained it wrong. The hostname is set and is correct. No problem with it. The problem is that I would like to get the ip address and ip configuration from the DHCP but I don't want the domain name set by the DHCP. The reason is that I don't have any control to the DHCP that is managed by our provider.

Answer (score 0):

How I solved it :

1. in Ubuntu use 127.0.1.1 instead of 127.0.0.1 to define the FQDN
2. set server_name@domain_name in `/etc/hosts` was not sufficient, i had to add server_name in the same line (`127.0.1.1 server_name@domain_name server_name`)

I was not able to change any of dhclient configuration to obtain a different domain name as the one that was automatically set by the dhcp (the none of our infrastructure provider). These very simple changes in `/etc/hosts` was sufficient.